# Magento 2: Why are my luma icons not showing?

Tags: magento2, theme, custom, fonts

I made a custom theme with luma as my parent theme.
Somehow it's only showing the icons of the blank theme and not the one of luma.

Do I need to copy any fonts or declare them in my custom theme?

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
  <title>My Theme</title>
  <parent>Magento/luma</parent>
</theme>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I had the following structure for my theme:

```
- web
-- css 
--- source
---- variables
----- _globals.less
---- _buttonset.less
---- _footer.less
---- _header.less
---- _navigation_extend.less
---- _productiongrid.less
---- _productview.less
---- _theme.less  //i changed this to _extend.less
---- _typography.less
```

I found the following DevDocs from the Magento website:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_mode.html

It said that you need to use the _extend.less file for extending styles of the theme you're using (in my case magento/luma)

In this file I had my @imports to the files in my structure. I deployed it through grunt and it worked.

Anybody knows why _theme.less didn't work? Is it used for different purposes?

Comment: If you created `_theme.less` without carrying over the contents from Luma then you would have either lost some variables or you'll be loading them from the blank theme. Which would explain why you lost the Luma icons, if I remember right there is a variable with `luma-icons` or something similar set.

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for the insight. I will look further into it!

Comment: Hi @BenCrook and Roy ,I have similar issue while I am creating custom theme by overriding Blank theme.I am not getting luma-icons in mini cart drop down and also when we override any module with web folder then it is broking all design.Please suggest how you resolve it.

Comment: Can you raise a new question and show your file structure and code changes please? It's hard to debug with only a small bit of info.

Answer (score 0):

I not sure about customise in your layout of your theme.

```
rm -r var/view_processed/* pub/static/frontend/*
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

If eveything works your theme should be extend all assets from luma. If you use grunt you can deploy theme again